# Python - getting os.popen to match a string?

Tags: python, match, os.system

I am trying to run a grep on a .doc file to get the strings and match it to evidence of macros in order to detect it.

I have:

```
filename = raw_input("file name: ") <--- using malicious.doc

    s1 = os.popen("grep '/vbaProject\|/vbaData' " + filename).read()
    s2 = 'Binary file ' + filename + ' matches'

    if s1 == s2:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

if I run:

```
    if s1 == s2:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

    print(s1)
    print(s2)
```

I get the following output:

```
false
Binary file malicious.doc matches

Binary file malicious.doc matches
```

the text matches, and I've even tried doing `s1 = str(s1) and s2 = str(s2)` and still getting false.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try a `print(repr(s1))` and `print(repr(s2))`? This way you could at least detect whitespace.

Comment: Thanks I think that might be the problem, getting this when I run that ```'Binary file malicious.doc matches\n'
'Binary file malicious.doc matches'```

Comment: yep, added \n to the end of it and it solved it!

Comment: Removing the whitespace will be more robust. On a windows system you probably would get a "\r\n" and your strings would be different again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your comment, you got an additional newline in the result.

I generally advise to strip results from whitespace before comparing them. In your case I would do:

```py
s1 = os.popen("grep '/vbaProject\|/vbaData' " + filename).read().strip()
```